# Align div horizontally without newline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've this html:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='container-element' id='el0'></div>
  <div class='container-element' id='el1'></div>
</div>
```

How can I align horizontally "container-element" div without newline?

Basically I want to view, initially, only element "el0".
Then, if I animate left "el0", I want to view "el1".

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmjU5/) is my basic fiddle, I can't find css combination to do what I need.

Comment: Obviously you can't fit two 500px-wide elements in one 500px-wide container side by side. And I see no trace of you trying to animate nor showing/hiding anything in your fiddle...

Comment: You want to set all divs in same line?

Comment: Yes all div in same line

Comment: You need to position div with left and make them in absolute position, try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kA83t/36/ Instead of create that two (or more class) you can count your child div and then multiply by your width and apply .css("left", w * n + "px") in your jquery

Comment: As in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kA83t/49/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
I'm only going off what you have mentioned in your query:

Two horizontally aligned DIVs that shift when you click on them. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/thePav/ZmjU5/18

CSS

```
.wrapper {width: 504px; overflow: hidden}
#container {border: 1px solid #000; width: 1004px; overflow: hidden}
.container-element {border: 1px solid #f00; height: 200px; width: 500px; float: left}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id='container'>
        <div class='container-element' id='el0'>  </div>
        <div class='container-element' id='el1'>  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.container-element').click(function(){
    $('#container').animate({
        marginLeft: -504
    }, 1000);
});
```

Very crude but it's a basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.container-element {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant align your divs if parent div dont greater width then both div's combined width

here is fiddle
[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SiddharthShah/n2GBX/)

```
JsFiddle
```

Comment: I need container 500px and element 500px (or 100%)

Comment: in that case replace div or give both divs 50% width

Comment: You may want to look into my answer. `white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: @NickDugger It will work but if parent dive has double width then child divs

Comment: You must not understand what white-space:nowrap does, you also do not understand the question, it seems.